# How to Structure REST API If It Contains Different Structures?

Tags: json, api, rest

Currently, I have an API end point that needs to return a list of items in a JSON format. However, each of the items that are returned has a different structure.

E.g. Think of a feed API. However, the structure of each item within the API can be very different.

Is it standard to return API response with multiple items - each with a different structure?

A made-up sample below to show different structures.

Store, Candy, and Personnel in the example is logically the same thing in my case (3 different items). Howevever, the structuring underneath can be very different - with different key-value pairs, different levels of nesting, etc.

```
{
   "store":{
      "book":[
         {
            "category":"reference",
            "author":"Nigel Rees",
            "title":"Sayings of the Century",
            "price":8.95
         
},
         {
            "category":"fiction",
            "author":"Evelyn Waugh",
            "title":"Sword of Honour",
            "price":12.99
}
      
],
      "bicycle":{
         "color":"red",
         "price":19.95
      
}
   
},
{
      "candy":
         {
            "type":"chocolate",
            "manufacturer":"Hershey's",
            "cost":10.00,
            "reduced_cost": 9.00
         
},
        },
{
      "Personnel":
         {
            "name":"chocolate",
            profile:
            {
               "Key": "Value",
               "Key": "Value",
               something:
               {
                
               "Key": "Value",
               "Key": "Value",
               }
            }
         
},
        },
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are no strict rules to REST in terms of how you design your payloads. However, there are still certainly things to consider obviously when doing so. Without knowing really the specifics of your needs it's hard to give specific advice but in general when it comes to designing a JSON REST API here is what I think about.

1. On average, how large will my payload be. We don't want to pass large amounts of data on each request. This will make your application extremely slow and perhaps even unusable on mobile devices. For me, the limit in the absolute worse case is 1mb and maybe this is even too high. If you find your payload is too large, break it down into separate resources. For example rather than including the books in the response to your stores resource, just reference the unique id's of the books that can be accessed through /stores/books/{id}
2. Is it simple enough that a person who stumbles across the resource can understand the general use of it. The simpler an API is the more useful it is for users. If the structure is really complex, perhaps breaking it into several resources is a better option
3. This point sort of balances number #1. Try and reduce the number of requests to get a certain piece of data as much of possible (still considering the other two points above). Excessively breaking down payloads into separate resources also reduces performance.

Comment: Will add to the good answer that it's nice to have field `type` in your response if it contains heterogeneous objects. That way it will be easier to parse on the client side. So that could  change structure of response a little bit.